# Audio recording software for Windows?

Tags: windows, audio, music-production, audio-recording

I am looking for audio recording softwares for Windows platform. I have to record a few songs.

I am looking for softwares other than Audacity, Adobe Audition, Sound Forge.

Requirements:

- 2 GB RAM (maximum)
- Windows (7 or earlier) platform
- Easy to Use.
- Easy to edit audios.
- Features like Noise reduction.
- Free or Paid

Comment: What do you not like about these 3 programs that you are trying to avoid?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [AudoEditMagic](http://www.mp3editmagic.com/aem/index.htm). The newest version release was in 2007, which makes it meet your low memory system requirements. Features:

- Low system requirements (functions with 166MHz Pentium processor)
- Windows 7 and earlier
- Fairly easy to use
- Simple editing with predefined and custom presets
- Noise reduction tool
- Free trial, and paid full version

Here's a screenshot from their website:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[OceanAudio](http://www.ocenaudio.com.br/) is freeware program developed by a research group from the Federal University of Santa Catarina in Brazil. It works on Windows, Linux and Mac, and besides all the basic features you'd expect from an audio editor, which can be used very easily, it also includes:

- Real-time preview of effects
- Multi-selection for delicate editions
- Efficient editing of large files
- Fully featured spectrogram

[image]